# C++ error: A reference of type cannot be initialized with a value of type

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I got a problem I can't find a solution to. I'm creating a entity - component system with smart pointers.

The error I get is:

> a reference of type `std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent, std::default_delete<PrimaryComponent>> &` (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type `std::unique_ptr<PlayerGraphics, std::default_delete<PlayerGraphics>>`

**The gameworld class:**

```
auto GameWorld::Setup_World() -> void
{
    player->Attach_Component(player_Graphics);
    Add_GameObject(player);
}
```

**The gameobject class attach component function:**

```
void GameObject::Attach_Component(std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent> &component)
{
    if (component != nullptr)
    {
        component_container.push_back(component);
    }
}
```

**The declaration of player_Graphics and player:**

```
class GameWorld
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> gameObject_List;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> player;
    std::unique_ptr<PlayerGraphics> player_Graphics
```

`player` is a `GameObject`, `player_Graphics` is a Graphics Component which derives from `PrimaryComponent`.

**The primary component class:**

```
class PrimaryComponent
{
protected:
public:
    PrimaryComponent();
    virtual ~PrimaryComponent();
    virtual void Render(GameObject &gameObject) = 0;
    virtual void Update(GameObject &gameObject, GameWorld &gameWorld, float gameTime) = 0;
};
```

**The PlayerGraphics class:**

```
class PlayerGraphics :
    public GraphicsComponent
{
public:
    PlayerGraphics();
    virtual ~PlayerGraphics();
    virtual void Render(GameObject &gameObject);
    virtual void Update(GameObject &gameObject, GameWorld &gameWorld, float gameTime);
};
```

PlayerGraphics derives from GraphicsComponent which derives from PrimaryComponent.

Comment: How is `player_Graphics` declared?  What is its exact type.  You don't show it.

Comment: Why do you write `auto GameWorld::Setup_World() -> void` when `void GameWorld::Setup_World()` is the desired form? Code, that looks more complicated doesn't execute faster. It doesn't make you smarter either.

Comment: Not answering your question, but passing `std::unique_ptr` by reference is kind of contradictory. I mean, `std::unique_ptr` is not to be shared, but by using references you are kind of sharing it.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `GameObject::Attach_Component` with the wrong type.  If you are going to use smart pointers, they should be of the same type.

Comment: #Mateusz Grzejek - Not trying to make the code smarter, just playing around with the features of c++ 11/14, I know it won't make the code faster or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the reference:

The line:

```
void GameObject::Attach_Component(std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent> &component)
```

should be:

```
void GameObject::Attach_Component(std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent> component)
```

And then, when you call it, instead of:

```
player->Attach_Component(player_Graphics);
```

you should do:

```
player->Attach_Component(std::move(player_Graphics));
```

That is, the function should take ownership of the pointer. Note that the original `player_Graphics` will be set to null (you moved it in, if you want to keep a reference ot that object then you are using the wrong tool).

You may be wondering why in your code passing a `std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent>` directly works, but passing a `std::unique_ptr<PlayerGraphics>` does not. Well the explanation is that you are using a non-const reference, and non-const references can only bind to an object of the exact same time. However if you pass the argument by value, then the smart pointer will be moved and it all will just work.

This all makes sense, `std::unique_ptr` is meant to be non-copyable, non-shareable, moveable smart pointers. You are expected to move the pointer around, not to pass it by reference.

TL;DR: If `B` is a subclass of `A` you can move a `std::unique_ptr<B>` into a `std::unique_ptr<A>` but you cannot bind a `std::unique_ptr<B>` to a reference of type `std::unique_ptr<a>&`.

PS. The constructor to move&cast is declared as follows:

```
template <class T, class D = default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr
{
    template <class U, class E>
    unique_ptr (unique_ptr<U,E>&& x) noexcept;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond. So when you make entity/component classes where the reference to the object is important, is raw pointers the way to go?

Comment: @Verdoner: That's a broad question to answer in a comment! My advice is to decide on the ownership of the objects (ownership is more or less the responsibility to delete). If the ownership if unique then `std::unique_ptr` is fine (other references to the same object may be raw pointers). If the ownership is shared (the last one to drop the pointer deletes the object) then use `std::shared_ptr`. And if you decide a crazy scheme where ownership changes depending on some flags... well, then raw pointers, delete manually, and good luck with that ;-)

Comment: Great answer ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling `GameObject::Attach_Component` with the wrong type.  It wants a `std::unique_ptr<PrimaryComponent>` but you are passing it a `std::unique_ptr<PlayerGraphics>`

**EDIT**

It doesn't matter if `PlayerGraphics` derives from `PrimaryComponent`.  That won't work with smart pointers, only raw pointers.

Comment: PlayerGraphics is a derived class of PrimaryComponent

Comment: Smart pointers, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, both allow cast to smart pointers of base classes, if used properly. As I say in my answer, the problem is not with the cast but with the reference, and that would happen also with raw pointers (imagine `Attach_Component(PrimaryComponent *&component)`).